# Store settings on user PC

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet with a script and it's saved on a remote location that every user can access.
This macro will let user select a target folder and create some files inside.

Now I want my script to remember the last chosen path of each user. I might need to store more paths (variables) in the future.

My idea is to store those data in a `Environ("AppData")` location on each users' computer. Sort of an offline cookie.

But what would be the easiest way to create (if it doesn't exist) read from and update file with multiple that I want to easily access?

I've tried it saving in notepad, but indexing and parsing was nightmare.

Comment: Create a hidden sheet where you can add entries for each user, you can retrieve user names with `Environ("username")`

Comment: SaveSetting/GetSetting is the easiest way to store named values (in the registry)

Comment: When it's on the remote location, it's set to read only. Even so, the spreadsheet would need to be shared (which is not user-proof) and it would ask to save changes after each use.

Comment: What about using an Access DB intead of notepad? I think it is easier to manage, cleanup etc than using registry, and much easier to parse and query than notepad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Save the settings to the registry.

> SaveSetting (appname, section ,key ,setting)

```
SaveSetting "AffectedTerminals", "frmMain", "LastDir", szPathname
```

Then you can retrieve the setting with getsetting the next time your app runs so you can use it.

> GetSetting ( appname , section, key [, default ] )

```
Dim szLastDir As String
szLastDir = GetSetting("AffectedTerminals", "frmMain", "LastDir", "P:\AttEngineering")
```

**EDIT: appname and section arguments explained.**
The appname and section can be anything you want. Something that describes the setting is best. In the above code AffectedTerminals was the name of my application. So if you have a spreadsheet that handles IT invoices then you might call the appname "ITinvoices". The section is just a sub section (sort of a sub-directory) for the regestry entry.

The setting will be saved at this locatioin

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/VB and VBA Program Settings/appname/Section/key/value/

So for mine it is saved as
[image]

**SaveSetting Function**

**AppName**
Required. String expression containing the name of the application or project to which the setting applies.

**Section**
Required. String expression containing the name of the section in which the key setting is being saved.

**Key**
Required. String expression containing the name of the key setting being saved.

**Setting**
Required. Expression containing the value to which Key is being set.

**GetSetting Function**

**appname**
Required. string expression containing the name of the application or project whose key setting is requested.

**section**
Required. String expression containing the name of the section where the key setting is found.

**key**
Required. String expression containing the name of the key setting to return.

**default**
Optional. Expression containing the value to return if no value is set in the key setting. If omitted, default is assumed to be a zero-length string ("").

Comment: This looks good, I just have a question about parameters "appname" and "section". Because my script is saved in excel, would the appname param be the full path to excel file? And sectioname can be anything or is there a logic to it? Thanks!

Comment: No, it can be anything you want. Something that describes the setting is best.  In the above code AffectedTerminals was the name of my application. So if you have a spreadsheet that handles IT invoices then you might call the app "ITinvoices".  The section is just a sub section for the regestry entry.  I'll explain in my answer in just a minute.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I'll wait couple of days if there are other options before accepting.

Comment: Glad to help. Let me know if you have any further questions on this.