# Save Variables and Parameters Values inside the VB Project

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have 2 userforms. One below is the *Main Menu*:

[image: Main-Menu form]

and the second has *Advanced Options*:

[image: Options form]

The second form is reading values and parameters from an Excel file (hidden worksheet), so every time I close the file it saves the parameters for next time I open the file.

**Question:** is there a way to store these variables inside the VB Project, in a way that they will be saved when closing the file, and next time when I open the file I can read them ?

Maybe there is a work-around by using some kind of a special class?

Comment: In general, variables (even global ones) are destroyed when excel is closed, so very hidden sheets are the best way to store that kind of data.  However, [this resource](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1135/Use-Excel's-hidden-data-store-to-share-data-across-VBA-projects.html), though complex and from _that other site with hyphens_, may be helpful for you in providing an alternative

Comment: @RGA thanks, but it only holds the data if you don't close Excel. So when our users power down / reboot after the weekend it will disappear

Comment: You could create a simple Access database with a table or two to store the values and read them from there via ODBC.

Comment: Check out this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970489/store-settings-on-user-pc/32970785#32970785  Here I answer how to store variables in the registry.  You will be able to read them the next time the program starts, but only on the same machine.  Might work for you.

Comment: @MatthewD great stuff, loves this solution, Thanks :)